# React with BrowserRouter: fetch manifest.json at path based on the current route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, create-react-app

React (CRA) using BrowserRouter from react-router-dom. Deployed on servers with static files & nginx.

UI1 has`<BrowserRouter basename="/">`

UI2 has `<BrowserRouter basename="/admin">`

Both are hosted on let's say domain.com so UI1 is right at domain.com and UI2 is at domain.com/admin.

There is a problem in UI1 that is not present in UI2. React always fetches a manifest.json file that is found at the same level as index.html. What would be correct is that UI1 asks for domain.com/manifest.json and UI2 asks for domain.com/admin/manifest.json.

It works fine as long as there are no extra `/` in the URI path. If I enter domain.com/a/b/c then UI1 fetches domain.com/a/b/manifest.json. However if I enter domain.com/admin/a/b/c then UI2 correctly domain.com/admin/manifest.json.

What I would like to find out is why UI1 and UI2 behave different, so that I can make UI1 fetch the right file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In `public/index.html`, I added `<base href="/" />` inside the `<head>`. This solved my problem.